# module 'trax.supervised' has no attribute 'inputs'

Tags: module, trax

I am working on a project involving Google's TRAX package.  I encountered the following error message while running a snippet of code on Jupyter notebook.

```
module 'trax.supervised' has no attribute 'inputs'
```

Is there a way around this issue?  I have trax version 1.2.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per trax documentation
The call must be trax.data rather than trax.Supervised
trax.data.inputs.add_loss_weights(generator, id_to_mask=None)

https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.data.html